# Call paramiko connect with ssh option -s

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Is it possible call this: `ssh user@1.2.3.4 -s netconf` in paramiko?

Or is there another way how to invoke netconf from paramiko?

Comment: You would have to get a channel from a paramiko transport and call `invoke_subsystem('netconf')` on the channel.  There is an example here:  http://rtoodtoo.net/how-to-upgrade-junos-remotely-via-netconf/  but maybe it'd be easier to use the `ncclient` module instead:  http://ncclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Perfect, the example http://rtoodtoo.net/how-to-upgrade-junos-remotely-via-netconf works well, but port number 22 is needed instead 830.